# How to use graphic objects as (scalable) plot labels

Tags: graphics

I'm sure I've seen this sort of thing done before, but now I can't find a working implementation anywhere.

Below I give a toy example that is just complex enough to illustrate the issues.  **(I provide full code after the problem's description.)**

---

First, consider this simple (and entirely meaningless) barchart:

```
In[122]:= With[
 {
   labels = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[-2];
               RandomSample[DictionaryLookup[{"English", ___}], nItems]
            ]
 },
 Framed[
  BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> labels
   , ChartStyle -> LightGray
   , BarOrigin -> Left
   , ImageSize -> 250
   ]
  , FrameStyle -> Thin
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> The goal is to replace the text labels along the left with `Graphic` objects, ("graphic labels", if you will), in such a way that these labels *scale appropriately with the figure*.

---

For this (rather artificial!) example, the "graphic labels" I have in mind consist of several colored `Rectangle` objects lined up in a row, like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(The black dot just marks the point (0, 0) in the barcode's internal reference frame; it is not part of the barcode.)

I defined a `barcode` function that, for any integer argument, generates a (random-but-reproducible) "barcode" like the one above.

Now, if I substitute such graphic labels for the text ones in the barchart, this is what I get:

```
In[124]:= With[
 {
   labels = Table[Graphics[barcode[i]], {i, Length[data]}]
 },
 Framed[
  BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> labels
   , ChartStyle -> LightGray
   , BarOrigin -> Left
   , ImageSize -> 250
   ]
  , FrameStyle -> Thin
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not great.  For one thing, the barcodes come out too big, and too far from the vertical axis.

But most seriously, the size of the barcodes does not change when `ImageSize` changes.  For example, if `ImageSize` is changed from 250 to 500, the result looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Confusingly enough, even though the size of the barcodes remains constant, the spacing *between* them changes in proportion to the change in `ImageSize`.

---

I'm looking for a way to set the size of the barcodes so that

1. the height of the barcode corresponds to 1 plot unit (or slightly less), *while preserving the barcode's original aspect ratio*;
2. the spacing between the barcodes and the (vertical) axis matches that between text labels and the axis;
3. both the size of the barcode and the spacing between one barcode and the next one, and between the barcodes and axis *scale with the image*; (needless to say, the barcodes should always be fully visible irrespective of image size).

With enough trial-and-error, I can find a "solution" that meets requirements (1) and (2) (see under the **Best so far** heading further below), but I have not been able to find one that *also* meets requirement (3).

The next section includes all the code referenced above; the last section documents some failed attempts at solving the problem.

---

### Code

```
nItems = 10;
data = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[-1];
   20 + RandomInteger[80, nItems]
];

With[{
  labels = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[-2];
    RandomSample[DictionaryLookup[{"English", ___}], nItems]
    ]
  },
 Framed[
  BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> labels
   , ChartStyle -> LightGray
   , BarOrigin -> Left
   , ImageSize -> 250
   ]
  , FrameStyle -> Thin
  ]
 ]

palette = ColorData[1, "ColorList"];
basewidth = 0.5;
baseheight = 1;
nstrips = 8;
baserect = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {basewidth, baseheight}];
barcode[index_] := BlockRandom[
  SeedRandom[index];
  Module[{colors = RandomSample[palette, nstrips]},
   Table[Translate[{colors[[i]], 
      baserect}, {(i - nstrips - 1) basewidth, -0.5 baseheight}], {i, 
     nstrips}]
   ]
  ]

Graphics[{barcode[1], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.05]}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Medium]

With[{
  labels = Table[Graphics[barcode[i]], {i, Length[data]}]
  },
 Framed[
  BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> labels
   , ChartStyle -> LightGray
   , BarOrigin -> Left
   , ImageSize -> 250
   ]
  , FrameStyle -> Thin
  ]
 ]

With[{
   labels = Table[Graphics[barcode[i]], {i, Length[data]}]
 },
 Framed[
  BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> labels
   , ChartStyle -> LightGray
   , BarOrigin -> Left
   , ImageSize -> 500
   ]
  , FrameStyle -> Thin
  ]
 ]
```

---

### Failures

**Best so far**

```
Module[{
  FUDGEFACTOR = <|"insetMultiplier" -> 200, "leftPadding" -> 40|>
  , n
  , makeInset
  },
 ; n = Length[data]
 ; makeInset[i_] := Inset[Graphics[barcode[i]]
   , Scaled[{-0.02, 0}, {0, i}]
   , {0, 0}
   , FUDGEFACTOR["insetMultiplier"]/n
   ]
 ; Framed[
  BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> None
   , ChartStyle -> LightGray
   , BarOrigin -> Left
   , ImagePadding -> {{FUDGEFACTOR["leftPadding"], Automatic},
                      {Automatic, Automatic}}
   , ImageSize -> 250
   , Epilog -> Table[makeInset[i], {i, n}]
   ]
  , FrameStyle -> Thin
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

- scheme requires fudge-factors that must be determined by trial-and-error;
- padding to make room for the barcodes does not scale appropriately when image is resized.

**Using `Scaled`**

```
Block[{baserect = 
   Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{basewidth, baseheight}]]},
 With[{
   labels = Table[Graphics[barcode[i]], {i, Length[data]}]
   },
  Framed[
   BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> labels
    , ChartStyle -> LightGray
    , BarOrigin -> Left
    , ImageSize -> 250
    ]
   , FrameStyle -> Thin
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

- swatches within barcode overlap
- overall scaling is wrong
- positioning is wrong

**Drawing labels in plot-space**

```
With[{
  labels = 
   Table[Graphics[Translate[barcode[i], {0, i}]], {i, Length[data]}]
  },
 Framed[
  Show[{
    BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> None
     , ChartStyle -> LightGray
     , BarOrigin -> Left
     , ImageSize -> 250
     ],
    labels
    }
   ]
  , FrameStyle -> Thin
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

- aspect ratio is wrong

**Using `Inset`**

```
With[{
  labels = 
   Graphics[Table[Translate[barcode[i], {0, i}], {i, Length[data]}]]
  },
 Framed[
  BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> None
   , ChartStyle -> LightGray
   , BarOrigin -> Left
   , ImageSize -> 250
   , ImagePadding -> {{50, Automatic}, {120, Automatic}}
   , Epilog -> Inset[labels, {0, 0}]
   ]
  , FrameStyle -> Thin
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

- overall scaling is wrong

Comment: Have you tried using the additional parameters for `Inset`? e.g `Inset[labels, Scaled[{-0.05, 0}], Scaled[{1, 0}], Scaled[1]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I modified my previous answer to work better with datasets of different length. I rely on the `AspectRatio` being `GoldenRatio`. If it isn't, replace `GoldenRatio` with the appropriate `AspectRatio`. I also use 3.6 as the width to height ratio of the barcode.

*edited to paint over axis below barcodes*

```
makeInset[i_,n_] := Inset[
    Graphics[barcode[i]],
    Scaled[{-0.02,0},{0,i}],
    {0,0},
    Scaled[{3.6,1}/n]
];

bplot[data_] := With[{n = Length[data]},
    Framed[
        BarChart[
                data,
                ChartLabels->None,
                ChartStyle->LightGray,
                BarOrigin->Left,
                PlotRangePadding->{{Scaled[3.6 / (n*GoldenRatio)],0},{0,0}},
                ImageSize->250,
                Epilog->{
                    White,
                    Rectangle[Scaled[{-1,-1}, {0, 0}], Scaled[{-.02, 1}, {0, 0}]],
                    Table[makeInset[i,n],{i,n}]
                }
            ],
        FrameStyle->Thin
    ]
]
```

A couple examples:

```
bplot[data]
```

[image]

```
bplot[data[[;;5]]]
```

[image]

The basic idea is to use a scaled inset size, and then increase the `PlotRangePadding` to accommodate the addition of the barcodes.

Comment: Thank you, but the x-axis in your proposed solution incorrectly extends into negative values.  Please the heading **Best so far** for what the desired solution looks like.

Comment: You can always paint over the axis by using something like: `Epilog->{White, Rectangle[Scaled[{-1,-1}, {0, 0}], Scaled[{-.02, 1}, {0, 0}]],Table[makeInset[i,n],{i,n}]}`

Comment: @kjo It would be useful to explain what you didn't like about my answer so that it could have been improved further. As far as I can tell, my answer met all of your requirements.

Comment: No problem with it.  (I was holding out for an answer that did not require painting over the axis.)

Comment: That's possible, although I think it requires postprocessing the graphic to remove the undesirable ticks, make the axis transparent, and place a line of the desired length over the transparent axis.

Comment: Thanks.  I just could not believe that *Mathematica* did not provide a way to do what I want to do without such post-processing (for example, a way to limit the axes to the `PlotRange`).  But that's the way it is, I guess.